# Two cursor keys not working on iBook G4

Tags: macos, keyboard, macbook, g4

The left and right cursor keys on my iBook G4 running Macos 10.4 do not respond.  Since this holds for both Aqua and X11, I am inclined to think that this is a hardware problem.

Are there any other checks I should do before seeking out the repair guy?

Comment: Could you be more specific ?

Comment: @Studer: About what "do not respond" means?  Pressing the keys does not result in any cursor movement, or other event that should be bound to the keys, either when used alone or when composed with modifier keys.  Or is something else unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds likely to be hardware, booting from a different system / backup of when it last worked should be able to tell you if it's software or not.

It's also pretty easy to reseat the keyboard connector on an iBook G4 if memory serves - so you might want to try that before dropping it off for repair.

Comment: This is the right idea.  I'll burn a Linux boot CD, and see what happens when I start up from that.

Answer (score 0):

Try plugging in a USB keyboard before you start mucking about with Linux disks ;-)